# Combining different data flows and create .txt file by sorting output

Tags: etl, talend

I have a requirement. I am trying to combining several data flows with Talend in order to create a .txt file. In my case the input flows are DB tables. I am able to create the output file "prova.txt", **but in this file some fields of 2nd and 3rd tables are missing** and I don't know why. I checked with tLogRow and the probelm seems to be in tHashInput_1. In the 3 tHashOutput rows are logged correctly with all fields.

Below, my job:

[image]
Components tHashOutput_2, tHashOutput_3, tHashInput_1 are linked to tHashOutput_1.

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone could help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for all thashoutput schema will be same, I attached image for your problem.
Here in all tfileoutputdelimited components give same file name, same schema and use append option. It will append data in same file from all 3 tables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback.Your solution helped me to find a way out. I also added a tUnite component to order my output result! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I noted that if I launch my job several times the file grow up and it keeps the old record. This is weird. Is there a way to remove and re-create the file?

Comment: You can use "file_name_"+TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd")+".format" so for each day there is one file. you can also modify if you want to append data in same file, for monthly or yearly basis.

Comment: I tried, but the file continue to grow up by keeping old record. It should not doing it

Comment: In you talend job, use tsetglobalvariable component and in that just define one global variable and in all tfileoutputdelimited component just use this variable. string you need to put in tsetglobalvaribel is TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getCurrentDate())

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, is to use tUnite, Assuming for all thashoutput schema will be same

[Example: Using tUnique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9wxo.png)

[image]

Regards!

[tunite](/questions/tagged/tunite)[talend](/questions/tagged/talend)[ecanaveras](/questions/tagged/ecanaveras)